# ReferenceError: push is not defined

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I was trying to push an array to my object Schema .But it says

> process.nextTick(function() { throw err; }); ReferenceError: push is
>   not define

here is the excerpt of code .

```
Database.comments.push(comment);
```

Please, can anyone tell me why ?

Comment: Check `Database.comments`, whether its exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

Database.comments should be an array